# Is it possible to have a multilanguage Environnement in SQL Server 2008 ide

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

is it possible to install another interface language to SQL Server 2008 Management Studio?

Im not talking about programming language but changing the interface language from English to French (or others). In Visual Studio, i can do it by installing the english and the french version of the product and then, in the option of Visual Studio, i can go to the Environnement Language and change from English to French.

Can i do the same with SQL Server 2008 Management Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

[BTW, what other language did you have in mind?  If you want to use LINQ to query, download [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)]

Comment: i have edited my first post to be more clear. I wasnt talking about programming language but the language of the interface. Changing from English to French like i can do with Visual Studio by installing the english and french version of the product.